# PushNotifications on Phonegap + jQueryMobile + iOS

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, apple-push-notifications

I'ld love to use this combination of Software for some simple push notifications.

Sending and Receiving isn't the problem - did it!

But how can I tell the jQueryMobile Application out of iOS that it is launched by PushNotification and shouldn't show the home screen but an other - notification related - screen instead?

Answer (score 0):

`Notification` object has a property `applicationLaunchNotification` which has value `1` if the application is launched via the notifictaion.

This below method queries the pending notification on the start of the application:

```
window.plugins.pushNotification.getPendingNotifications(function(notifications) {
     if(notifications.length > 0){
          var note = notifications[0];
          if(note.applicationLaunchNotification == "1"){
              // do the processing
          }
     }
});
```

For detail - https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/PushNotification

Comment: That's not the point. Question is, how to tell the HTML-Part of the Application, that a new notification is there and switch to different screen?

Answer (score 0):

use can change you app deligate code and enable push in application pro-vising profile
        #import "AppDelegate.h"
        #import "MainViewController.h"

```
    #import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>

    @implementation AppDelegate

    @synthesize window, viewController;

    - (id)init
    {
        /** If you need to do any extra app-specific initialization, you can do it here
         *  -jm
         **/
        NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

        [cookieStorage setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];

        self = [super init];
        return self;
    }

    #pragma mark UIApplicationDelegate implementation

    /**
     * This is main kick off after the app inits, the views and Settings are setup here. (preferred - iOS4 and up)
     */
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
    {
        CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

        self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] autorelease];
        self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

        self.viewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        self.viewController.useSplashScreen = YES;

        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

        return YES;
    }

    // this happens while we are running ( in the background, or from within our own app )
    // only valid if __TESTING__-Info.plist specifies a protocol to handle
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL*)url
    {
        if (!url) {
            return NO;
        }

        // calls into javascript global function 'handleOpenURL'
        NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"handleOpenURL(\"%@\");", url];
        [self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];

        // all plugins will get the notification, and their handlers will be called
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification object:url]];

        return YES;
    }

    // repost the localnotification using the default NSNotificationCenter so multiple plugins may respond
    // ADD OUR NOTIFICATION CODE

    #pragma mark - Push notification Delegate Methods

    -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
    {
        NSString *token = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:      [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
        token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
        //NSLog(@"content---%@", token);
    }


    -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
    {

        //flagPushConfirmation=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"startPush"];
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                  message:@"Device not Register for notification"
                 delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message show];

    }

    -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    {
       UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notification"
          message:@"Recieve Notification" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"otherButtonTitles:@"ok",nil];
        [message show];
    }


    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
    {

        UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
        if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
            // WAS RUNNING
            NSLog(@"I was currently active");

            NSString *notCB = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"foreground"];
            NSString *notID = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"notificationId"];

            NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString
                                     stringWithFormat:@"%@(%@)", notCB,notID];


            [self.viewController.webView  stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];

            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
        }
        else {
            // WAS IN BG
            NSLog(@"I was in the background");

            NSString *notCB = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"background"];
            NSString *notID = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"notificationId"];

            NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString
                                     stringWithFormat:@"%@(%@)", notCB,notID];
            [self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];

            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
        }
    }
    - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window
    {
        // iPhone doesn't support upside down by default, while the iPad does.  Override to allow all orientations always, and let the root view controller decide what's allowed (the supported orientations mask gets intersected).
        NSUInteger supportedInterfaceOrientations = (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);

        return supportedInterfaceOrientations;
    }
```